# not able to target element

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, tailwind-css

I have HTML Like this

```
<element1 class="class__1">
   <element2 removePadding></element2>
   <element3 class="class-3"></element3>
</element>
```

I want to change the margin-bottom of class-3 only when element2 has `removePadding` attribute, I tried like this

```
element1 element2[removePadding] element1 element3.class-3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

but this didn't work.

I want to target that `class-3` *only when* element2 has `removePadding` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element1 element2[removePadding] element1` - The last `element1` shouldn't be there, CSS selectors only can go down, not up. Furthermore  `element3` is not child of `element2` but is a sibling so you could use the `+` ([next-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator)) selector

```css
div div[data-removePadding] + div.class-3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #020202;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="class__1">
   <div data-removePadding=""></div>
   <div class="class-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of the sibling selector with the class-3 selector:

```
element1 element2[removePadding] ~.class-3 {
   margin-bottom: ...
}
```

As the other comment mentioned, CSS selectors can only go down/next and not up/previous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has` pseudo-class and the child combinator (>) to achieve the wanted result!

```
element1:has( > element2[removePadding] ) > element3.class-3 {
  /* your code goes here */
}
```

Comment: Agreed, will change it to "can".